# how to delete the ^M from standard output and standard error

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, expect

I runs the **inventury.expect** ( expect script ) from ksh script  ,

and I transfer the standard output and standard error to log file - /tmp/VM.log

until now evry thing is ok

```
  #!/bin/ksh

  .
  .
  .

  /var/tmp/inventury.expect 1>>  /tmp/VM.log 2>>  >>/tmp/VM.log


  .
  .
  .
```

but when I looked in the log file , I see there allot of control M ( ^M)

so I add the tr command as the following in order to delete the ^M from **standard out/err**

```
  /var/tmp/inventury.expect 1>> | tr -d "^M" /tmp/VM.log 2>> | tr -d "^M"  >>/tmp/VM.log
```

but seems this not illegal

I get: ( when I runs my ksh script )

```
  syntax error near unexpected token `|' ,    when I run the ksh script
```

please advice how we can to delete the ^M from standard output and standard error ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `tr` is the right idea, but the character to remove won't be specified with `^M`. What those control characters indicate are carriage returns, which you specify in the shell with `\r`.  So replace your uses of `tr -d "^M"` with:

```
tr -d '\r'
```

Put that after the expect script, redirecting the output from `tr` to the files:

```
/tmp/inventury.expect | tr -d '\r'  1>> /tmp/VM.log 2>> /tmp/VM.log
```

Comment: so I need to add the tr -d '/r' after the pipe line?

Comment: I get the same error , maybe the pipe line is the problem ?

Comment: @maihabunash I've rewritten to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: That won't affect stderr at all.

Answer (score 0):

I set the syntax as

```
  /var/tmp/inventury.expect | tr -d '\r' 1>> /tmp/VM.log  2>> /tmp/VM.log
```

this solved the ^M